# Properly looping AsyncTask that parses JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I've got an android application. I extended AsyncTask class like that:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {
        String jsonData = Webserv.getTaskJson(data[0]);
        taskArrayList.clear();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject t = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String taskString = t.getString("id");
                String latString = t.getString("lat");
                String lonString = t.getString("lon");
                String adrsString = t.getString("adrs");
                taskArrayList.add(taskString+ "#" +latString + "$" + lonString + "%" + adrsString); 
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        dialog.dismiss();
        taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(v);
    }

}
```

Function getTaskJson returns JSON String that I then parse. Parsed strings are printed in ListView items. Everything works fine (even though cutting those strings seems silly to me, but I've got no better idea how to get the data other way)

```
taskList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) viewClicked;
            String clicked= tv.getText().toString();
            String idTaskClicked = clicked.substring(0, clicked.indexOf('#'));
            String latTaskClicked = clicked.substring(clicked.indexOf('#')+1, clicked.indexOf('$'));
            String lonTaskClicked = clicked.substring(clicked.indexOf('$')+1, clicked.indexOf('%'));
            String adrsTaskClicked = clicked.substring(clicked.indexOf('%')+1);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASK_ID, idTaskClicked);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME, getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_USERNAME));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASK_LAT, latTaskClicked);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASK_LON, lonTaskClicked);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASK_ADRS, adrsTaskClicked);

            startActivity(intent);

        }   

    });
```

Well, anyway, this all works fine for now. The problem is: I need to have this application kind of synchronized with my webpage. In order to keep it "synchronized" I would like to LOOP this AsyncTask that gets JSON and parses/puts Tasks into ListView. For example, I want to "refresh" this ListView with new values after, let's say 2 minutes. Any suggestions how could I do that? And one more question: after clicking an item from a listview, I start new Activity. Am I going to experience any problems with AsyncTasks (actually got two of them: one for parsing JSON, second for plain sending POST with geo coordinates) after clicking "back" in that new Activity (going back to given one here).

Kind regards!

Comment: for refresh `ListView` with new values after 2 minutes you can use service

Comment: Could you say something more? Any example? I need to make that POST every 2 minutes, then parse and repeat all the stuff.
+Is it a good idea to use service when I have things like that, that should be done outside UI Thread? I'm beginner @all this stuff, sorry if asked about something silly

Comment: see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html please

Comment: Please don't do that.. [AsyncTask should never run more than a few seconds](http://http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: And I want it to run for a few seconds. But I want it to run for a few seconds now, and I want it to run for a few seconds after 2 minutes, and after 4 minutes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Timer and TimerTask to execute AsyncTask on specified time intervals, but remember that TimerTask executes on worker thread and you should execute AsyncTask only on UI thread so you will have to use handler or runOnUithread method to properly execute AsyncTask.

If you choose to use Timer, then invalidate in in onPause and restart in onStart, you dont want updates when app is in background. If you want you need to add more logic, like store temporary list to be used once your Activity is recreated.

Also, I see you are clearing list inside your doInBackground which is currently used by your ListView, this is wrong, you should return new list contents from doInBackground and update ListView in onPostExecute, otherwise you are introducing data race.

Comment: Well, the first thing I thought was to clear the whole list before parsing this JSON and getting list from the beginning, somehow I found it logical. I'll keep in mind your advice and I'll try to make it the way you suggested, thanks:)